How to pass data using Next.js Link component without showing it in the URL?
I'm currently working on a Next.js application and I need to navigate between pages while passing some data without exposing it in the URL. I know that the Link component from Next.js allows me to navigate between pages, but I’m unsure how to achieve this without appending the data to the URL.
import Link from 'next/link';

const SourceComponent = () => {
  const dataToPass = { key: 'value' };

  return (
    <Link href="/target-page" passHref>
      <a>{/* Some content */}</a>
    </Link>
  );
};

In this example, the data is not passed to the target-page. I want to access the "dataToPass" on targeted page.
I also tried using router.push to navigate programmatically:
import Link from 'next/link';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const SourceComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dataToPass = { key: 'value' };

  const handleClick = () => {
    router.push({
      pathname: '/target-page',
      query: { data: JSON.stringify(dataToPass) }, // This exposes the data in the URL
    });
  };
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to Target Page</button>
  );
};

In this case, I noticed that the data still gets appended to the URL.
Thank you for your help!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The answer depends on your use case and what kind of data you want to pass. One way is using React Context API for sharing data between pages.
Assuming you are using NextJS with App Router, you need to create a context provider component and wrap your application with it.


// src/providers/EnvironmentProvider.tsx

'use client';

import {
  ReactNode,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useMemo
} from 'react';


type EnvironmentContextType = {
  data: any;
  setData: (params: any) => void;
};

const ENVIRONMENT_CONTEXT_DEFAULT_VALUES: EnvironmentContextType = {
  data: {},
  setData: () => {}
};

const EnvironmentContext = createContext(ENVIRONMENT_CONTEXT_DEFAULT_VALUES);

export const useEnvironment = () => useContext(EnvironmentContext);

type EnvironmentProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export const EnvironmentProvider = ({
  children
}: EnvironmentProviderProps) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>({});

  const values: EnvironmentContextType = useMemo(() => ({
    data,
    setData
  }), []);

  return ( <
    EnvironmentContext.Provider value={
      values
    }>{
      children
    }<
    /EnvironmentContext.Provider>
  );
};





// src/app/layout.tsx

import { EnvironmentProvider } from '@/providers/EnvironmentProvider';

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <EnvironmentProvider>
          {children}
        </EnvironmentProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



Consider replacing any with the correct types (or remove any typing if use use JS).
Updated SourceComponent and TargetComponent:


import Link from 'next/link';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { useEnvironment } from '@/providers/EnvironmentProvider';

const SourceComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { setData } = useEnvironment();
  const dataToPass = { key: 'value' };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setData(dataToPass);

    router.push({
      pathname: '/target-page',
    });
  };
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to Target Page</button>
  );
};

const TargetComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useEnvironment();

  return (
    <h1>{data.key}</h1>
  );
};



More detailed guide from Vercel Using React Context for State Management with Next.js.

Thank you for your suggestion regarding the Context API! I appreciate the input and will definitely consider that solution. but Is there any attribute in the Next.js Link component that allows me to pass data to another component without exposing it in the URL? I would love to know how I can access that data in the targeted component. Thanks again for your help!

As far as I know, Next.js doesn't provide API to pass data through Link or useRouter unless you use URL params resource/{id} or search params resource?key=value. There are relevant discussions though Pass custom prop or data to Next JS Link component, Pass props through Link that can provide more information.

okay, Thanks for the clarification! Appreciate your insights on how Next.js handles data passing through Link and useRouter. It's helpful to know the limitations and alternatives.
